# How to implement clicklistener on adapter on kotlin wiouth null listener?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to implement a listener on a recyclerview adapter. the thing is that I have donde that other times and it works fine, but this time it does not.
The adapter is call from a popupview, could that be it?

this is where the debug shows me the error on the adapter class

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): CarListItemViewHolder {
    //inflate view
    val v: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_car_list_item, parent, false)
    v.setOnClickListener(this)
    return CarListItemViewHolder(v, mListener as OnItemClickListener)
}
```

on the return statment it says that "mListener" is null

```
fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
    mListener = listener
}
```

Again, I have several other adapters and I use them the same way.
Any help or suggestion on what to look for, would be great.

Comment: its not 100% clear. But it seems you have to use setOnItemClickListener to set the listener and v.setOnClickListener(this) might be v.setOnClickListener(mListener)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I haven´t implemented it yet on the parent class. I will take a look at it

Comment: yep, that was the problem. I haven't implemented the onclicklistener on the parent class. again thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because on the parent class I did not implement the onclicklistener. Once I did that, the error was gone

```
carListItemAdapter!!.setOnItemClickListener( object: CarListItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onClick(position: Int) {

        }

        override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ClickListener to adapter where you are setting your adapter -

```
adapter.setOnClickListener(this)
```